# Continuity (from above) theorem

Tags: probability

Let $\mathcal{A}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_2 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_3 \supseteq \cdots$ be a sequence of non-increasing sets with elements in the sample space $\mathcal{S}$.   Define the union of the sequence as the set:

$$\mathcal{A} \equiv \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_k.$$

Show that $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}_k)$.  Can someone please provide the proof and explanation as to why this is the case?  I am confused on how I would show this to be true.

Comment: For questions like this, you will need to tell us what you have already tried, and where you are getting stuck.  Note that you are essentially trying to prove that probability is continuous on monotone sequences.  I would suggest you try to re-express the event $\mathcal{A}$ in a way that involves a union of disjoint events, then apply the countable additivity property to get your proof.  Try some working along these lines.

Comment: I first took the complement of $\mathcal{A}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_2 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_3 \supseteq \cdots$ and used the fact that $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ results in $\mathcal{A^c} \subseteq \mathcal{B^c}$ to result in $\mathcal{A^c}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{A^c}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A^c}_3 \subseteq \cdots$. I used the continuity theorem (from below ) to get $\mathbb{P}{(\cup^{\infty}_{k = 1} \mathcal{A^c}_k)} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}_k)$ which

Comment: results in (by De morgan's law) $\mathbb{P}{{(\cap^{\infty}_{k = 1} \mathcal{A}_k)^c}} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A^c}_k)$. At this point I get stuck.

Comment: You are almost there. Notice that the left-hand side of your last equation is equal to $1 - \mathbb P(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal A_k)$. Can you make it from here?

Comment: I really wouldn't ask the question if I could. Do you mind explain what I am missing?

Comment: This expression is the *intersection,* not the union!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've now offered an explanation of your attempted working (in the comments) I'm going to provide a solution.  This property of the probability measure is often referred to as "continuity from above", and it follows as a consequence of countable additivity.  The property is usually established via the corresponding property of "continuity from below", but here I will fold that result in to give a proof that only uses the properties of sets and the axioms of probability.

(I note from your comments that you are trying to prove the result by invoking continuity from below.  That is not particularly helpful without also proving continuity from below, since these are essentially just variations on the same substantive result.)

Since $\mathcal{A}_1 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_2 \supseteq \mathcal{A}_3 \supseteq \cdots$ we have $\overline{\mathcal{A}}_1 \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{A}}_2 \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{A}}_3 \subseteq ...$, which means we can form disjoint sets of the form $\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k - \overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}$ for $k \geqslant 2$.  Using DeMorgan's law and the countable additivity property, we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}) 
= \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_{k} \Bigg) 
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \ \overline{\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_{k}} \ \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \overline{\mathcal{A}}_k \ \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_1 \cup \bigcup_{k=2}^\infty (\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k - \overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}) \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} ( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_1) - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb{P} (\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k - \overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} ( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_1) - \sum_{k=2}^\infty [ \mathbb{P} (\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k) - \mathbb{P}(\overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}) ] \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P} ( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_1) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{k=2}^n [ \mathbb{P} (\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k) - \mathbb{P}(\overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}) ] \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg( 1 - \mathbb{P} ( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_1) - \sum_{k=2}^n [ \mathbb{P} (\overline{\mathcal{A}}_k) - \mathbb{P}(\overline{\mathcal{A}}_{k-1}) ] \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1 - \mathbb{P} ( \overline{\mathcal{A}}_n) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} ( \mathcal{A}_n). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(The penultimate step in this equation involves recognition of cancelling terms in the sum.)

Comment: +1 This answer clearly isolates the key concepts and relates them to the underlying (simple) probability axioms.

Answer (score 1):

For a decreasing sequences of sets $\{\mathcal A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ we note that $\{\mathcal A_k^c\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence. Further (as you have mentioned already)
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal B_k\right) = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb P(\mathcal B_k)$$
when $\{\mathcal B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is increasing. It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal A_k\right) &= 1 - \mathbb P\left(\left[\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal A_k\right]^c\right) = 1 - \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal A_k^c\right)  \\
& = 1 - \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb P(\mathcal A_k^c) = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}[1 - \mathbb P(\mathcal A_k^c)] \\&= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(\mathcal A_k).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what this working actually adds.  It uses monotone continuity (for an increasing sequence) as a premise, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @ben I see your answer is more "complete," but I have to say that I don't understand your comment. From OP's trials, it is clear that OP is already familiar with the continuity (from below) property and is struggling to derive continuity (from above). So, I was helping from there.

Comment: It is an example of a question-begging proof --- one that assumes another theorem as a premise, that is essentially just a variation of the theorem to be proved.  Proofs of that kind are generally not particularly useful, since they simply show that variations of the same essential result imply one another.

Comment: I completely agree with you; it's at best a simple corollary. But from the comments, I thought that's what OP was struggling with? Anyways, I see that a complete answer would be better for others who come across this post.

Comment: You may well be right --- the OP might be just looking for the corollary.  My view is that in these cases we should still give answers that discourage that kind of thinking, and seek the actual "substance" of the proof of the result.  What you have given here may well be useful to the OP if that is their sole concern, but I think it is generally better to eschew question-begging proofs.  Anyway, (+1) for your answer and thoughtful comments.

Comment: I see your point. I'll keep that in mind when answering/commenting on questions.